# dynamic scoping rules work differently after redefining an autoloaded function without changing its code

Tags: org-babel, autoload, dynamic-scoping

Evaluate the following code:

```
(package-initialize)
(unless package-archive-contents (package-refresh-contents))
(package-install-selected-packages)

(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages '((emacs-lisp . t)))

(defun test () result) 
(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'test)
```

Then in org-mode, try to evaluate the block

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
0
#+end_src
```

In the `*Messages*` buffer, you should see `run-hooks: Symbol’s value as variable is void: result`.

`result` is bound locally within `org-babel-execute-src-block`. When I run `org-babel-execute-src-block`, `test` is not able to "see" `result`.

However, if I copy the source code defining `org-babel-execute-src-block` into the org buffer and evaluate it. Then when I run the src block, `result` is visible to `test`.

phil's comment pointed me to the fact that `org-babel-execute-src-block` is using lexical binding.

What is going on here? It seems that the bindings are associated with the file in which the defun was evaluated. But `test` is dynamically scoped, and so I would expect it to be able to "see" `results`. Perhaps if a function `f` using dynamic binding is executed within a function `g` using lexical binding, `f` won't be able to "see" bindings made in `g`.

Comment: Did you copy that function to a different file, or is that function definition only ever being evaluated in the original org library?  (If you copied it elsewhere, you probably haven't matched the file-local `lexical-binding` of the original file in your custom file.)

Comment: Anyhow, "autoloaded functions" aren't different wrt scoping rules.  If you call a function which only exists as an `(autoload...)` declaration, then the required file is `load`ed, and all the functions in that file are defined under the scoping rules for that file (based on the file-local `lexical-binding` declaration, if any, in that file's first line).

Comment: The top line of `ob-core.el` (where `org-babel-execute-src-block` is defined) contains `lexical-binding: t`. Presumably, `org-babel-execute-src-block` has lexical binding, but after I copy and re-evaluate the definition (with `C-x C-e`) it has dynamic binding. This doesn't quite explain why `my-org-babel-after-execute-show-graphics` cannot "see" `result-params`. Perhaps if a function `f` using dynamic binding is executed within a function `g` using lexical binding, `f` won't be able to "see" bindings made in `g`

Comment: I have rewritten the question to make it simpler and more reproducible. I hope it will be easier to follow :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `result` is a `let`-bound lexical variable in the `org-babel-execute-src-block` function (which is defined in ob-core.el which uses `-*- lexical-binding: t; -*-`).

This means that `result` is visible *only* to the code of `org-babel-execute-src-block` within the `let` form.  This is what "lexical scope" means -- only the code which is *written* within that `let` form can see it<sup>1</sup>.

The definition/code of your `test` function is not within that lexical scope, so no `result` variable exists there.

Conversely, variables with *dynamic* scope are globally visible until the form which binds them has completed.  Dynamic variables must be defined with `defvar` (or similar) in order to be recognised as dynamic by code which uses lexical-binding.

In files which do *not* use lexical-binding, OTOH, *all* variables are dynamic.  So if you redefine `org-babel-execute-src-block` under dynamic binding, the `let`-bindings in the new function will be dynamic variables, and hence your `test` function sees a value for `result`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Notwithstanding any macro calls within the lexical scope, in which case the macro itself *is* defined elsewhere, but the *expansion* is generating code within the same lexical scope as the call (replacing the call to that macro) *before* the function is actually defined.

Comment: You should mention that `lexical-binding` has a default value of `nil`, so when the code is evaluated from inside the org file then it is evaluated using the dynamic scope rules.

Comment: That makes sense. Except that when I copy and evaluate the code defining `org-babel-execute-src-block` into a buffer other than the org buffer, `results` is still invisible to `test`. Yet if it is copied and evaluated in the same org buffer as runs the src block, `test` can see it.

Comment: Which other buffer?  Depending on which version of Emacs you're using, some lisp buffers (notably `*scratch*`) may default to lexical-binding.  Check `C-h v lexical-binding` within that buffer.

Comment: `*scratch*` has `lexical-binding` equal to `t`

Comment: That is the explanation! When I was redefining it from within `*scratch*`, it was still using lexical binding. If i create a new buffer, and evaluate it there, it then becomes a function with dynamic binding.

Comment: Yes, when you redefine the function, it is defined using the scoping rules for the file/buffer in which you have evaluated the function definition.  If you copy it to \*scratch\* and evaluate it, it will use lexical binding.  If you copy it to a lisp buffer using dynamic scope and redefine it there, it will use dynamic scope.